# IIS Manager - Cant start W3SVC and IIS Admin is missing from Service

Tags: web-services, iis, service, webserver, iis-manager

I am trying to start `W3SVC` on Windows 10 but I am facing several issues here:

I went to `Task Manager` and clicked the *Services* tab then I found the `W3SVC` service and I right clicked it and choose `start` but it **did not** start. I tried to click it several times.

I do have `IIS Manager` but `IIS Admin` is missing from `Services` which I do not know why.

`World Wide Web Publishing Service` is turned on and it is running `automatically` The dependencies tab have everything in there as it should be. HTTP Service and Window Process Activation Service

I did try to restart IIS in command prompt `iisreset`. But it failed and the error appeared:

`The IIS Admin Service or the World Wide Web Publishing Service, or a service dependent on them failed to start.  The service, or dependent services, may had an error during its startup or may be disabled.`

I am trying to run a custom website I created on `IIS Manager` but it wont start. The error appeared:

`Cannot start service w3svc on computer`

I tried to start "World wide web publishing service", but I was unable to start it as it said:

`Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start`

I want to start the website that I created in my `inetpub` and I want this `w3svc` up and running

Answer (score 2):

- open Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features->Turn windows features on or off -> Uncheck "Internet Information Services" and "Windows Process Activation Service"
- Restart your machine.
- open Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features->Turn windows features on or off -> install both "Internet Information Services" and "Windows Process Activation Service"

if you still face issue then check the event viewer log.

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands on cmd:

```
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters /v GenerateKeys /f
net start w3svc
net stop apphostsvc
net start apphostsvc
```